# Firmware update daemon service hanging during 'software updater' execution

Tags: 18.04, uefi, update-manager, bios, fwupd

I have a Dell PowerEdge T330 that I purchased without any existing OS. I installed Ubuntu 18.04 LTS. When LivePatch used system updater to update the system for the first time it sets up a bunch of software and then gets into following lines:

```
Setting up fwupd (1.2.10-lubuntu2~ubuntu18.04.3)
Installing new version of config file /etc/fwupd/daemon.conf
Installing new version of config file /etc/fwupd/remotes.d/lvfs-testing.conf
Installing new version of config file /etc/fwupd/remotes.d/lvfs.conf
Installing new version of config file /etc/fwupd/remotes.d/vendor.conf
Installing new version of config file /etc/fwupd/uefi.conf
fwupd-offline-update.service is a disabled or a static unit not running, not starting it.
```

The software updater hangs after this line and the 'cancel' button is disabled. Since the updater has not moved beyond this line for over an hour, so I checked the `fwupd.service` status and this is I what I see:

```
fwupd.service - Firmware update daemon
Active: active (running)
Main Pid:....
Tasks:...
Cgroup: ....

Starting Firmware update daemon...
fwupd[17104]: FuPluginUefi         kernel efivars support missing: /sys/firmware/efi/efivars
```

I checked `/sys/firmware/` it looks like my system is using legacy bios perhaps. The only directories I found were `acpi`, `dmi`, and `memmap`.

How do I get out of this situation? Is it safe to close the software updater? Why is software updater daemon service configuring uefi when it looks like my firmware is running using legacy bios?